# Google App Engine NodeJS Prevent Crashing Server

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

We are running NodeJS in the App Engine standard environment and while we try to be perfect programmers, we some times have a bug, the issue we're running into app engine completely crashes the server every time and throws a 203 error.

We've tried to do all the standard error handling things for Node, but it seems like app engine is a special case. Has anyone seen this or handled this issue before?

Comment: What are `perfect programmers`? ;)

Comment: Seriously, you need to provide a lot more info if you expect an answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: Are you having a bad day Dan?

Answer (score 0):

As it is stated in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51769527/10301041:

"The error 203 means that Google App Engine detected that the RPC channel has closed unexpectedly and shuts down the instance. The request failure is caused by the instance shutting down."

An error in your code can be the cause of that. Other cause might be one of the project quotas.

If you still running on the issue and you can't identify the source of the error I would suggest to contact GCP support, as it is also suggested in the answer above.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but how do we not have the entire crash in this case? We're not running out of quota certainly and that's exactly what we've now done is by a support package to deal with this issue. Originally they said their was a known issue with the nodejs 8 stack, but we've pushed it back to them as after that was resolved we're still seeing it.

Comment: I would recommend you continue working with GCP support since this is an specific error code that is potentially related with the gRPC or the nodejs runtime.